# Why does java force all interface members to be public?

Tags: java, interface, access-modifiers

Suppose I have a file `test.java` with the following:

```java
interface IA {
  void f();
}

class A implements IA {
  public void f() {
    System.out.println("test");
  }
}
```

`void f()` in interface `IA` is public by default as mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/interfaceDef.html#:%7E:text=The%20public%20access%20specifier%20indicates,same%20package%20as%20the%20interface.):

> All abstract, default, and static methods in an interface are implicitly public, so you can omit the public modifier.

This forces me to include the `public` modifier in my implementation of `f` in class `A`. Why does java force all implementations of interface members to be fully `public`? What if I only wanted `f` to be accessible from my own package?

## EDIT to clarify

Interfaces are by default `package-private` but interface *members* are by default `public`. In the code example I show above, this forces me to declare `A`'s implementation of `f` as `public`. But I don't see why this *has* to be the case. Consider the following table from the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html):

| Modifier | Class | Package | Subclass | World |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| public | Y | Y | Y | Y |
| protected | Y | Y | Y | N |
| no modifier | Y | Y | N | N |
| private | Y | N | N | N |

Why can the interface *member* `f` *not* be package-private or `protected`? In this case the implementing class `A` is not in another package, but in the same package. Therefore `public` is too "public" for my purposes. Furthermore it breaks the rule of thumb mentioned in the docs:

> Use the most restrictive access level that makes sense for a particular member. Use private unless you have a good reason not to.

Comment: As long as your interface and class are not public the scope should be limited to your package. Maybe create 2 interfaces, one for public and one without modifier, in the public interface you don't declare f

Comment: Interface exposes the **contract**, describes list of actions that class can perform. Implementation details might be incapsulated and hidden, but **contract** must be visible and therefore always public

Comment: I think it's purely a Java design choice. The interface exposes a contract and so it's supposed to be public for that. However, there may be valid arguments to want protected/package-private methods and when I wondered about it, I didn't find any answer about this.

Comment: @Charles at the top level, java allows the same flexibility with `interface` as it does with `class`. Namely either package-private or `public`. At the member level, this is not the case. `private` and `protected` are not allowed as far as I know, which is why I'm confused. Please see edit to my original question.

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko please see edit to my original question. I'm referring more to modifying access to the interface members rather than the interface itself.

Answer (score 0):

Your `A` class has the default modifier. So you can start by reducing accessibility by the class modifier. An interface is a public contract (but interface itself does not need to have the public modifier. It can have the default modifier for example.). So, if it is a public contract and you implement it, is because you want to say to the world that you follow that contract. You can always implement a method without implementing the interface. You loose the interchange that interface allows.

So think for a second. You have class `A` that says it implements `IA`. Your class, since implements `IA` is used somewhere else, since follow the public contract. If you have reduced the visibility of that method what will occur? The implications of breaking the contract are too many. It's like you have a collection that implements List, and then you make all interface methods that you implement private. What happens when you try to use you class as an interface instance?

In Java you cannot reduce a method visibility when implementing an interface or extending a class.

Comment: An interface is *not* a public contract. It is in fact package private by default. It's members are public by default, but that doesn't automatically make them available to other packages (i.e. the World). The interface *must* be declared public before that can occur (i.e. `public interface {...}`)

Comment: Public contract is different from public modifier. I used the term public contract that is easier to describe what is the purpose of an interface. I can also call it a protocol, a common behaviour to several classes, etc.

Comment: My question isn't about the purpose of an interface. It's more about why java chooses to use package private as the default top level access modifier, and public as the default member access modifier.